# Do wifi extenders dongles in mb/s equal total (network card plus extender)

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

So I have an internal network intel card AC 3165 and it has a pretty good MB/s, yet I am curious, if I added a wifi extender, would both work and increase the total speed?  If not, would I be better to try and run a solution using the ethernet port and if so, do you have any recommendations i.e. range extender to the router than a laptop?

Edit: unable to change the network card on laptop, or not that technically minded to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends what you mean by extender. Any kind of WIFI repeater will at best have no impact but will likely rdfuce the available spectrum and thus speed using ethernet instead of or between APs will almost always be better.

Comment: Fair enough, and makes sense, however, other than ethernet over power, and running a cable in my rental property, is there any other solution which, could bring ethernet from my modem to my laptop?

Comment: And alternatively, if my wireless network card has dual band wireless than a dual band router would be a fix?

Comment: I deployed that way in the past (prior to the AC standard using routers in the "A"  standard which was not widely used by end devices). Its quite viable, but, of-course limits the client bandwidth choice. Another possibility is Ethernet over power (eg powerline) to link the APs